# No such file or directory 'fiile'

Tags: python

i have a problem , i want to run a file from the srollbar in python 3 when i run the code it shows me an error : No such file or directory 'fiile' 
I want to send the file that is in the scrollbar by pressing the send button , 
i already specified the command of the send button

```
import serial
import time
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *


moha = Tk()
def file(tk_event=None, *args, **kw):
    fiile= filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('txt files','.txt'),('all 
    files','.*')])
    file_path.set(fiile)
    fichier = open(fiile, "r")
    print(fiile)


def moh():
    # Open grbl serial port
    s = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0',115200)

    # Open g-code file
    f = open('fiile', 'r')

    # Wake up grbl
    s.write("\r\n\r\n").encode("utf8")
    time.sleep(2)   # Wait for grbl to initialize
    s.flushInput()  # Flush startup text in serial input

    # Stream g-code to grbl
    for line in f:
        l = line.strip() # Strip all EOL characters for streaming
        print ('Sending: ' + l)
        s.write(l + '\n') # Send g-code block to grbl
        grbl_out = s.readline() # Wait for grbl response with carriage return
        print( ' : ' + grbl_out.strip())

    # Wait here until grbl is finished to close serial port and file.

    raw_input("  Press <Enter> to exit and disable grbl.")

    # Close file and serial port

    f.close()
    s.close()
file_path = StringVar()
entry = Entry(moha, textvariable=file=path)
entry.place(x=155, y=114)
b1= Button(moha, text="Selectionner un fichier", background='White', command=file).place(x=290, y=112)
b2= Button(moha, text="Send", background='White', command=moh).place(x=120, y=170)
```

Thanks for all

Comment: Are you certain that the code you're showing here is the code you're using? It looks like you're trying to open `"fiile"`, the string literal, not the variable `fiile`

Comment: @aryamccarthy I don't  know how to do it :/

Comment: **Are you certain that the code above is the code you ran?**

Comment: Can you specifically state where in the above code the error is occuring? Also, please note that in `entry = Entry(moha, textvariable=file=path)`, there seems to be a typo. Consider editing it.

Comment: @aryamccarthy yes

Comment: @Dashadower the error is in the line   :   # Open g-code file
    f = open('fiile', 'r')

Comment: @MohamedElHadi Then replace that line with `f = open(fiile, "r")`

Comment: @Dashadower the error now is : NameError : name 'fiile' is not defined

Comment: Clearly your example is not the code you are running, because these are basic syntax errors that are easy to diagnose visually but are not present above. I'm moving to close.

Comment: @aryamccarthy the problem is solved thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set your `file_path` variable to the file path of the `filedialog`. So you can just call `file_path.get()` to get the file path.
In function moh:

```
#Open g-code file
f = open(file_path.get(),"r")
```

Comment: Thank you so much you saved me